# How can we apply custom class for landing page and product page?

Tags: css, class

How can we apply custom class for landing page and product page?
Ex: i want 100% width on landing page and custom width on product page

Comment: you have installed theme?

Comment: yes.. i have installed

Comment: this is the site http://mg.adoptcure.com/. manager wants that banner should be 100%, i added class but its effecting all pages